# Could <samp> support be added to Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering

Since Stack Exchange already supports [`<kbd>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-KBD) for text *input*, it only makes sense to support the matching *output* from a program, [`<samp>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-SAMP), distinctly from the program [`<code>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-CODE) itself.

If there is value to supporting [`<pre>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-PRE) and these others in addition to Markdown's backticks and indent, adding `<samp>` would provide similar value, both in allowing HTML to be pasted and supported, as well as styling context (such as not attempting to syntax highlight the content).

Comment: Also, please add support for <blink> and <marquee> tags. ;)

Comment: Those are presentational, rather than semantic markup!

Comment: What do you mean by "support"? What would text in such a tag look like?

Comment: By "support" I mean adding it to the list of allowed tags; not stripping it. As far as style, I'd assume it would look similar to <kbd>, i.e. monospace font, maybe different colors or bolded.

Comment: See also [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).

Comment: I was just about to ask this same question, then found to my disappointment that it was asked more than four years ago and still the `samp` element is not supported in Stack Overflow markup.

Comment: @Arkanon This is the problem with closed, permission-based systems.